# Difference in Ambient air and Environmental air

Tags: differences

Is there any difference between the followings?

- Ambient air
- Environmental air

In the case we denote the air surrounding some objects (e.g. building), which is appropriate to use?

Are they differently used for different scale of the air(e.g. 10m and 100km)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ambient air** is used much more widely in [scientific literature](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ambient%20air&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiLlq36rbfcAhWUXCsKHWdfCmYQ_AUIDigA&biw=1366&bih=650), while **environmental air** is [a common company name](https://www.google.com/search?q=Environmental%20air&client=firefox-b&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjSydeDrrfcAhVDWisKHYfOBqkQ_AUICSgA&biw=1366&bih=650&dpr=1).

Therefore, **ambient air** is your word of choice, regardless of scale.

Comment: The phrase "Environmental air" is used in various research papers such as, Environmental air pollution, Environmental air samples, Environmental air analysis.

Comment: Regardless, "ambient air" is still more widely used compared to "environmental air", so I don't think anyone would blame you for using it: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ambient+air%2Cenvironmental+air&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CAmbient%20air%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cenvironmental%20air%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't know this kind of tool.